# Find a gap in a group of ranges with optional inequalities

Tags: c#

There's a bunch of similar questions on SO, but none that seem to answer what I'm asking.

I have a class like so:

```
public partial class PercentileWeight
{
    public virtual Guid VotingWeightId { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal LowerBoundPercentageRanking { get; set; }

    public virtual bool LowerBoundInclusive { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal UpperBoundPercentageRanking { get; set; }

    public virtual bool UpperBoundInclusive { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal PercentageWeight { get; set; }
}
```

... the concept here is, if a data source is ranked within a certain percentile, the value of their data may count more or less in a decision tree that consumes that data.  For example, if the data source is ranked in the top 10%, I might want to double the value weight of the data source.  The object for such a PercentileWeight would look something like this:

```
var pw = new PercentileWeight
    {
        UpperBoundPercentageRanking = 100M,
        UpperBoundInclusive = true,
        LowerBoundPercentageRanking = 90M,
        LowerBoundInclusive = false,
        PercentageWeight = 200M
    };
```

Note the `UpperBoundInclusive` and `LowerBoundInclusive` values.  In this model, a ranking of exactly 90% would *not* qualify, but a value of exactly 100% *would* qualify.  There will also be logic to make sure that none of the ranges overlap.

What I'd like to do is programmatically identify "gaps" in a collection of these objects, so I can show I user "uncovered ranges" for them to create `PercentileWeight` objects for them.

I want to present the user with a "prefab" `PercentileWeight` object covering the first gap; for example, if the above object was already in the system, the user would be presented with a *potential* object resembling:

```
var pw = new PercentileWeight
    {
        UpperBoundPercentageRanking = 90M,
        UpperBoundInclusive = true,
        LowerBoundPercentageRanking = 0M,
        LowerBoundInclusive = true,
        PercentageWeight = 100M
    };
```

Here's the problem: it seems this should be relatively straightforward, but I have no idea how to do this.  Can someone suggest a relatively performant way of identifying the gaps in a collection of such ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those problems that seems simple but is a little tricky to implement in practice. Here is an extension method which will create new `PercentileWeight`'s to fill in all the gaps between a range.

```
public static class PercentileWeightExtension
{
    public const decimal Delta = 0.00000000000000000000000001M;

    public static IEnumerable<PercentileWeight> CoveringRange(this IEnumerable<PercentileWeight> inputs, PercentileWeight coveringRange)
    {
        //todo: following code expects no overlaps check that none exist

        //create lower and upper weights from coveringRange
        var lower = new PercentileWeight(decimal.MinValue, true, coveringRange.LowerBoundPercentageRanking, !coveringRange.LowerBoundInclusive);
        var upper = new PercentileWeight(coveringRange.UpperBoundPercentageRanking, !coveringRange.UpperBoundInclusive, decimal.MaxValue, true);

        //union new lower and upper weights with incoming list and order to process
        var orderedInputs = inputs.Union(new [] { lower, upper })
            .OrderBy(item => item.LowerBoundPercentageRanking)
            .ToList();

        //process list in order filling in the gaps
        for (var i = 1; i < orderedInputs.Count; i++)
        {
            var gap = GetPercentileWeightBetweenLowerAndUpper(orderedInputs[i - 1], orderedInputs[i]);
            if (gap != null)
            {
                yield return gap;
            }
            //dont want to output last input this represents the fake upper made above and wasnt in the original input
            if (i < (orderedInputs.Count - 1))
            {
                yield return orderedInputs[i];    
            }
        }
    }

    private static PercentileWeight GetPercentileWeightBetweenLowerAndUpper(PercentileWeight lowerWeight, PercentileWeight upperWeight)
    {
        var lower = lowerWeight.UpperBoundPercentageRanking;
        var lowerInclusive = lowerWeight.UpperBoundInclusive;
        var upper = upperWeight.LowerBoundPercentageRanking;
        var upperInclusive = upperWeight.LowerBoundInclusive;
        //see if there is a gap between lower and upper (offset by a small delta for non inclusive ranges)
        var diff = (upper + (upperInclusive ? 0 : Delta)) - (lower - (lowerInclusive ? 0 : Delta));
        if (diff > Delta)
        {
            //there was a gap so return a new weight to fill it
            return new PercentileWeight
            {
                LowerBoundPercentageRanking = lower,
                LowerBoundInclusive = !lowerInclusive,
                UpperBoundPercentageRanking = upper,
                UpperBoundInclusive = !upperInclusive
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can be used pretty easy like this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //existing weights
        var existingWeights = new[] {
            new PercentileWeight(90, false, 95, true) { VotingWeightId = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new PercentileWeight(50, true, 60, false) { VotingWeightId = Guid.NewGuid() }
        };
        //get entire range with gaps filled in from 0 (non inclusive) to 100 (inclusive)
        var entireRange = existingWeights.CoveringRange(new PercentileWeight(0, false, 100, true)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Which outputs a new list containing these items (all new items have a `VotingWeightId` of `Guid.Empty`)

- 0 (non inclusive) to 50 (non inclusive) (New)
- 50 (inclusive) to 60 (non inclusive)
- 60 (inclusive) to 90 (inclusive) (New)
- 90 (non inclusive) to 95 (inclusive)
- 95 (inclusive) to 100 (inclusive) (New)

Comment: Wow... so the reason I couldn't think of a straightforward way to do it was because it was not straightforward?  Good to know.  I will try this out and report back, thanks!

Comment: I did it slightly differently, but this got me where I needed to go.  Thanks!